# Implementing Map Span with Dynamic Coordinates

Tags: swiftui, ios17

I have a map (iOS 17) that displays the three Apple maps types (standard, hybrid, and imagery). When the hybrid or imagery map is displayed for the first time it is zoomed in to the max and out-of-focus. It appears to be a problem with the span. I would like to set the span to fix this, but it works much differently than previous versions of iOS.

Most of the examples online are using static coordinates while I am using dynamic coordinates. There is a CodeWithChris.com example using a camera view inside .safeAreaInset that allows setting the view size:

```
camera = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200))
```

but it is doesn't appear possible to use this with the main map view.

Thanks for looking!

```
struct DetailView: View {

    var item: TravelEntries    // <-- coordinates arrive from CoreData Transaction
    @Binding var mapType: Int

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: item.entryLat,
            longitude: item.entryLong)
    }

    var selectedMapStyle: MapStyle {
        return switch(mapType) {
        case 0: .standard(elevation: .realistic)
        case 1: .hybrid
        case 2: .imagery
        default: .standard(elevation: .realistic)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Map() {
                Marker(item.entryCatName ?? "", coordinate: coordinate)
                    .tint(.red)
            }
            .mapStyle(selectedMapStyle)

            ShowMapPicker(item: item, mapType: $mapType)
            ShowDetails(item: item)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching around the web I discovered that I can set the map initial position with Map(initialPosition: .region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: , Span())))

```
struct DetailPortView: View {

    var item: TravelEntries
    @Binding var mapType: Int

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: item.entryLat,
            longitude: item.entryLong
        )
    }

    var selectedMapStyle: MapStyle {
        return switch(mapType) {
        case 0: .standard(elevation: .realistic)
        case 1: .hybrid(elevation: .realistic)
        case 2: .imagery(elevation: .realistic)
        default: .standard(elevation: .realistic)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Map(initialPosition: .region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: (MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005))))) {

                Marker("\(item.entryCatName ?? "") purchase", coordinate: coordinate)
                    .tint(.red)


            }
            .mapStyle(selectedMapStyle)

            ShowMapPicker(item: item, mapType: $mapType)
            ShowDetails(item: item)
        }
    }
}
```